# Send account balance with web3js

Tags: javascript, web3js

I want to send the account balance of the wallet, or have web3 deduct the sending fee from the wallet.

This currently is my code:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");

const app = async (phrase) => {

   const bscProvider = new HDWalletProvider(
      phrase,
      'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org'
   );

   const ethProvider = new HDWalletProvider(
      phrase,
      'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/***********************'
   );

   const bscweb3 = new Web3(bscProvider);
   const ethweb3 = new Web3(ethProvider);

   const Accts = await bscweb3.eth.getAccounts();
   const Acct = bscAccounts[0];

   const bscBal = await bscweb3.eth.getBalance(Acct, "latest");
   const ethBal = await ethweb3.eth.getBalance(Acct, "latest");

   const newAcct = await ethweb3.eth.accounts.create();



   try {

       try {
        await ethweb3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: Acct, to: newAcct.address, value: ethBal });
       } catch (error) {
        console.log("eth err: " + error.message);
       }

       try {
        await bscweb3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: Acct, to: newAcct.address, value: bscBal });
       } catch (error) {
        console.log("bsc err: " + error.message);
       }
   } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
   }




   bscProvider.engine.stop();
   ethProvider.engine.stop();


   return newAcct;

};






module.exports = app;
```

what I get after running this code is:

> eth err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

> bsc err: insufficient funds for transfer

Is there how I can make web3 deduct the gas fee from balance or how I can do the calculation to get the fee ?